# unsigned char rotate

Tags: c, rotation, twos-complement, unsigned-char

I'm a little bit confused as to what an unsigned char is. A signed char is the representation of the char in bit form right? A sample problem has us rotating to the right by n bit positions, the bits of an unsigned char with this solution:

```
unsigned char rotate(unsigned char x, int n) {
    unsigned char temp = x << 8 - n;
    x = x >> n;
    return (x | temp);
}
```

If anyone could explain with char examples and their respective bits, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `unsigned char` tells the compiler to treat the underlying bit pattern as a number from 0 (00000000) to 255 (11111111).  Declaring it a `char` tells the compiler to apply [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to the underlying bit pattern and treat it as a number from -128 (10000000) to 127 (01111111).

Consider a 3-bit number.  If it is unsigned, you have:

```
000 = 0
001 = 1
010 = 2
011 = 3
100 = 4
101 = 5
110 = 6
111 = 7
```

If it is signed you have:

```
100 = -4
101 = -3
110 = -2
111 = -1
000 =  0
001 =  1
010 =  2
011 =  3
```

What is neat with respect to arithmetic (as that link mentions) is that you don't have to treat signed binary numbers differently than unsigned ones.  You just do the actual binary math without regard to signed or unsigned.  But you do have to apply the signed/unsigned interpretation to the inputs and to the output.

In the signed realm you might have:

```
2 + (-3) = 010 + 101 = 111 = -1
```

But in the unsigned realm this is:

```
2 + 5 = 010 + 101 = 111 = 7
```

So it's all a matter of interpretation since the actual bit patters being added and the bit pattern of the sum are the same in both cases.

Comment: Gotcha. How do you know the bitwise representation of a char?

Comment: Take the 3-bit example I gave and extend it to eight bits. `10000000` is `-128`, `11111111` is `-1`, `00000000` is `0`, `00000001` is `1`, and `01111111` is `127`.  You should be able to work out the rest.

Comment: `char` isn't necessarily signed. It is on Windows, but typically it's unsigned on ARM. It's also not necessarily either 8 bits big or two's complement, but exceptions there are pretty rare.

Comment: @raphnguyen don't forget, a char (as a letter or sign or sth.) is nothing more than a number as any other integer type. It is only a sign, when interpreted by the displaying routine (be it console, GUI, ...).

Comment: Hmm alright, so assuming I have a bit `1111 0000` and I want to rotate it to the right by 3 positions, it should be `0001 1110` right? So, 8 - 3 = 5. Shift `1111 0000` 5 positions to the left would be `0000 0000`. Shift `1111 0000` 3 positions to the right would give `0001 1110`. Then the OR of `0000 0000` and `0001 1110` is nothing more than `0001 1110`?

Comment: In a signed char it shifting may or may not result in the shift of the sign bit, it is implementation dependent. And also the default qualification of char is also not defined and is implementation dependent, so to be safe unsigned char should be defined.

Answer (score 3):

`signed char`, `char` and `unsigned char` are all integer types. For the sake of simplicity I'll assume that CHAR_BIT is 8 and that signed types are 2's complement. So:

- `signed char` is a number from -128 to +127
- `unsigned char` is a number from 0 to 255
- `char` is either the same range as `signed char`, or the same range as `unsigned char`, depending on your C implementation.

As far as C is concerned, a character is just a number within the range of the `char` type (although various character functions like `tolower` require the value to be cast to an unsigned type on the way in, even if `char` is signed).

So, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are *both* representation of the character in bit form. For numbers in the range 0 to +127 they both use the same representation (there's only one way to represent positive numbers in binary). For numbers outside that range, the signed representation of a negative number `n` is the same bits as the unsigned representation of `n + 256` (definition of 2's complement).

The reason this code uses `unsigned char` is that right-shift with a negative signed value has implementation-defined result. Left shift with a negative signed value has *undefined behavior*. Usually left-shift behaves the same as for unsigned values, which is OK, but right shift inserts bits at the left-hand-side with value 1, a so-called "arithmetic shift", which isn't what's wanted here. Unsigned values always shift in zeros, and it's the shifting in of zero that lets this code build the two parts of the rotated result and or them together.

So, assuming an input value of x = 254 (`11111110`), and n = 1, we get:

```
x << 7 is 0111111100000000
x >> 1 is         01111111
|      is 0111111101111111
convert to unsigned char to return is 01111111
```

If we used a signed type instead of `unsigned char`, we'd quite possibly get:

```
x is -2                           11111110
x << 7 is 11111111111111111111111100000000 (assuming 32-bit int, since
           smaller types are always promoted to int for arithmetic ops)
x >> 1 is implementation-defined, possibly 
          11111111111111111111111111111111
| is      11111111111111111111111111111111
convert to signed char to return is -1
```

So the bit-manipulation with the unsigned char results in the correct answer, rotated by 1 bit to move the 0 from the end to the start. Bit-manipulation with the signed char, probably gives the wrong result, might give the right result if negative signed values do a logical right shift, but on really unusual implementations could do anything.

Pretty much always for bit-manipulation tasks like rotate, you want to use unsigned types. It removes the implementation-dependence (other than on the width of the type), and avoids you having to reason about negative and non-negative values separately.

Comment: @phoxis: question has now been tagged `twos-complement`, so if you think that's wrong you'll have to argue it out with the questioner and QuantumMechanic (who added the tag). sign-magnitude is really very rare indeed among C implementations, and I don't even know what behavior was common for shift operators on systems that used it. So I can't provide those examples, but again there's no guarantee in C that it will give the right answer.

Comment: I should take a closer look about the implementation. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

an unsigned char is just an 8-bit integer type that can take values between 0 and 255 and a signed char can take values between -127 and 128. In the actual machine code there is no real difference, except one: when you do a right shift on a signed type using >> (be it char, short or int) it is carried out as an arithmetical shift, meaning for negative values (which have a 1 as MSB) a 1 is shifted in, instead of a 0 and the above code will not work as expected.

**EDIT:** Your above code example of rotating an unsigned char by 3 bits for signed and unsigned:

00110101 rotated unsigned and signed is 10100110.

but for a number whit a 1 in front you get an arithmetic shift and thus

11010001 rotated unsigned is 00111010.
11010001 rotated signed is 11111010.

Comment: Arithmetic shift on signed values is not guaranteed by the standard (see 6.5.7/5: "If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
resulting value is implementation-deﬁned.")

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not know that. But I suppose most compilers will do it. I know VC does and I'm quite sure gcc will do it, too. But you're right in that it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, it's only a minor point. In most places the code would give the wrong answer for "rotate" if it used a signed type due to arithmetic shift. It's just me being pedantic saying that in theory an implementation is *allowed* to give the right answer :-)